# Does Core Animation makes use Quartz2D and OpenGL 3D or they are at same level in OSX architechture?

Tags: macos, core-animation, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I have slight confusion in apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/OSX_Technology_Overview/MacOSXOverview/MacOSXOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001067-CH205-BCICAIFJ).
I am not able to understand that in Graphics and Media Layer, Core Animation is above Quartz framework or in the same line?
From [image](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/OSX_Technology_Overview/art/osx_architecture.jpg) it looks below. Am I right?

Does Core Animation makes use Quartz2D and OpenGL 3D or they are at same level?

Thank you
Rahul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear from the illustration, but Core Animation makes use of OpenGL (for compositing) and Quartz (for rendering 2D graphics), so it's a higher-level framework than the other two.

Quartz is tightly integrated with Core Animation and the two are often used in combination, for example when animating a custom layer/view that's drawn with Quartz.

OpenGL is mostly abstracted away by Core Animation and while there is some glue for special applications (like games), you usually wouldn't use OpenGL directly while using Core Animation.

Comment: Also, there are hints of the overlay of Core Animation on top of OpenGL showing in things like how the CATransform3D struct has the exact same internal structure as the OpenGL model view matrix.  Core Animation triggers the use of the high-end GPU in the newer dual-GPU MacBook Pros, as well, showing that it's relying on the 3-D graphics hardware.

Comment: @omz & @Brad: Thank you for response. In interface builder, under the View Effects tab, there is a option that if we want core animation layer or not. So if we tick Context View we get core animation later. Now I see that the contents there after are not drawn on currentContext(view), but new Bitmap Context is created for them. Why? Also, if its a new bitmap context then it should use bitmap created out of it to Draw on currentContext(view), but it does not. My basic question is, What is going on there?

Answer (score 0):

Even 11 years later Quartz rendering in 2D is still all done on the CPU. Only Windows in 18.04 was able to move Font Rendering and 2D to the GPU. The GPU is only for compositing.

Comment: I added this comment because in 2022 this is googles top answer for "is macos quartz 2d gpu accelerated"